# Configuring code parameters in Android Studio for exception handling based on build targets?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing in Android Studio. I'm using ACRA for crash reporting.

However, when I'm running/building locally, I want to comment out the line

// ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", mailTo = "somebody@gmail.com", mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST, resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)

So I can handle the debugging in the emulator.

But, when I compile for release, I don't want to forget to comment this line back in :)

Is there an easy way to set this up? Perhaps with Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, here's what I did.

- Include the annotation with all configuration.
- In my main Application.onCreate() method, I put in

  if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
      ACRA.init(this);

Now it only enables ACRA if it's the signed production build!